Spy movie spanning pre WW2 to Cold War
I’m looking for a very old colour film:
The film follows the life of a single person who gets kicked out of a private school, goes into British intelligence and revolutionizes the intelligence agency during World War II, using hookers to gather intel on Germans, etc.
The movie continues, I believe, into the Cold War era, and ends when a bomb goes off killing his wife while he was the intended.


I believe the movie you're looking for is this: 
Spymaker: The Secret Life of Ian Fleming (1990)
It's a mostly fictional (read highly imaginative) account of the life of the Bond author :-)
Here's the trailer
And here's a page with an exhaustive summary and lots of pics.
Warning: There's some nudity among those screenshots!
